# Creating a bar chart with two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a dataframe that includes two columns with the product name and its calories.

```
Item         Calories
Beer           200
Hamburger      320
```

I'd like to create a bar chart showing the product and the calories for each product but I would like the bars to have the same colour.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Item'])['Calories'].mean()
df2.plot.bar()[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Does `df.plot(kind='bar')` not work? You can just feed it a vector of custom colours

Comment: Thanks @yatu. I was a bit stupid. I have just changed the code and I got the result I expected:tocalories_by_product = df.groupby(['Item'])['Calories'].mean()

calories_by_product.plot.bar(color='blue');

Comment: The tricky thing is to customise the colours, that is if you want a specific color or colormap for the bars. But they are all the same colour by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calories_by_product = df.groupby(['Item'])['Calories'].mean()

calories_by_product.plot.bar(color='blue');